# How can I dynamically create a name of a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, naming

I am having a function in python

```
def func(dataFrame,country,sex):
    varible_name=dataFrame[(dataFrame['land']==country) & (dataFrame['sex']==sex)]
```

Now, for example, I call this function

```
func(dataFrame,'England','M')
```

I want that variable name be `England_M` instead of variable_name.

Comment: No, you certainly do *not* want that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That is a bad design pattern. You can get close to this by using a dictionary; `mydict = {England_M: myvalue}`. That gives you almost all the advantages of what you ask without the disadvantages.

Comment: Use a dictionary (by the way, this is a legitimate question, so just ignore those dislikes).

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. So, probably it's a bad idea to do so. I did find many links suggesting to use dictionary. Probably that remains the best option.

Comment: If you really want an underscore, try something like: `my_dict['{}_{}'.format(country, sex)] = ...`

Comment: Yes, that's what Arnaud is also suggesting below. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Martin Why so complicated? `my_dict[(country, sex)] = ...`

Comment: As the OP wanted an underscore?

Comment: @Martin In a hypothetical variable name, yes; but just to create a dict key, a tuple is probably better.

Comment: I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in Python.
What you can do instead is store the results under a dictionary with key = `England_M` for instance.

In your case, you could do the following :

```
def func(dataFrame,country,sex):
    tmp = dataFrame[(dataFrame['land']==country) & (dataFrame['sex']==sex)]
    variable_name = "{c}_{s}".format(c=country, s=sex)
    return dict(variable_name=tmp)
```

Now using it :

```
results = func(dataFrame, "England", "M")
print(results['England_M'])
```

Comment: you *can* but you *shouldn't*

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yea like that `locals()['my_var_name']='some_vale'`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis oh wow, didn't even know about that. Yep, doesn't seem like a safe option.

Comment: Thanks folks for suggestions. It seems these work arounds should work.

Comment: @Oliver Note that using a dict is not a "workaround"; it's *sane design*. "Variable variables" are a workaround for not using appropriate data structures.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed right. I agree. My apologies! Thanks a lot for your inputs.