# Creating multiple pyspark dataframes from a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to dynamically create multiple dataframes in pyspark based on the values available in the python list

My dataframe(`df`) has data:

```
date        gender balance
2018-01-01   M     100
2018-02-01   F     100
2018-03-01   M     100

my_list = [2018-01-01, 2018-02-01, 2018-03-01]
for i in my_list:
  df_i = df.select("*").filter("date=i").limit(1000)
```

Could you please help?

Comment: I want to split the existing pyspark dataframe into 3 dataframes just based on dates and hence i have created a list with distinct values and i tried filtering based using filter function by passing the date.

Comment: Yes, I understood it now. Sorry, my bad. Mohan, `list` is a keyword and should not be used as a variable name. I made an edit in accordance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can create the names of dataframes dynamically in `PySpark`. In Python, you cannot even [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622683/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-name-of-a-variable-in-python) assign the names of variables, let alone `dataframes`.

One way is to create a dictionary of the `dataframes`, where the `key` corresponds to each `date` and the `value` of that dictionary corresponds to the dataframe.

*For Python:* Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973687/create-new-dataframe-in-pandas-with-dynamic-names-also-add-new-column), where someone has asked a similar Q on name dynamism.

Here is a small `PySpark` implementation -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
values = [('2018-01-01','M',100),('2018-02-01','F',100),('2018-03-01','M',100)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['date','gender','balance'])
df.show()
+----------+------+-------+
|      date|gender|balance|
+----------+------+-------+
|2018-01-01|     M|    100|
|2018-02-01|     F|    100|
|2018-03-01|     M|    100|
+----------+------+-------+

# Creating a dictionary to store the dataframes.
# Key: It contains the date from my_list.
# Value: Contains the corresponding dataframe.
dictionary_df = {}  

my_list = ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01']
for i in my_list:
    dictionary_df[i] = df.filter(col('date')==i)

for i in my_list:
    print('DF: '+i)
    dictionary_df[i].show() 

DF: 2018-01-01
+----------+------+-------+
|      date|gender|balance|
+----------+------+-------+
|2018-01-01|     M|    100|
+----------+------+-------+

DF: 2018-02-01
+----------+------+-------+
|      date|gender|balance|
+----------+------+-------+
|2018-02-01|     F|    100|
+----------+------+-------+

DF: 2018-03-01
+----------+------+-------+
|      date|gender|balance|
+----------+------+-------+
|2018-03-01|     M|    100|
+----------+------+-------+

print(dictionary_df)
    {'2018-01-01': DataFrame[date: string, gender: string, balance: bigint], '2018-02-01': DataFrame[date: string, gender: string, balance: bigint], '2018-03-01': DataFrame[date: string, gender: string, balance: bigint]}
```