# selecting multiple rows with a list of id pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a table in spark, which has ID and numOfReq attributes.
in ID, it is between 1 to 100 and it's not in order, and each ID can be repeated many times in the table. I want to extract rows with 1, 47, 54 and 89 IDs. I can do it with a for loop like this pseudo code:

```
temp = [None , None, None, None]
i = 0
for id in idList:
    temp[i] = table.filter(table['ID'] == id)
    i += 1
```

but it took a long time to do so.
is there any filter or library which do this fast? what should I insert in my code? I need something in pyspark

Comment: Do you want 4 different tables for 1, 47, 54 and 89  respectively? Secondly, you use `id` in the `for` loop and then use `temp[i]`? `i` is undefined. You mention that it took you a lot of time, so did you try it in PySpark?

Comment: i is iteration counter and that's pseudo code. yes, I need exactly that for tables and in pyspark it took a long time to be done.

Comment: i is not a problem, the problem is to select that 4 tables.

Comment: Your pseudo-code looks fine though.

Comment: Check this - may be this solves your problem, though the logic used is quite similar, but with dictionary instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743574/creating-multiple-pyspark-dataframes-from-a-single-dataframe/

Comment: Are you looking for `table.where(table["ID"].isin(idList))`?